# Touches doesn't work on UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

I have this strange issue. To start it all, this is how my view hierarchy
looks like:

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` with three separate `ContainerView's` inside it. Each of the `ContainerView's` `frames` (and respective `UIViewControllers`) are set programatically.

I open the second `ContainerView` with a `UIView.animate(...)` method. Inside this `UIView/UIViewController` I have a `UITableView`. The problem is that only the first five (and half of the sixth for some reason, but maybe that's a clue) `UITableViewCell's` are selectable. I have about five more `UITableViewCell's` which is for some reason not selectable.

I don't have any `UITapGestureRecognizer's` which has been the problem for some other people that I've seen. Also, if I add the `TouchesBegan` to either the `UITableView` or the `UIViewController` holding it, it behaves in the same manner. That will say, it only prints out when I touch the same part of the screen where the `UITableViewCell'`s are selectable.

Is there anyone that have encountered the same issue or something similar to it that can shed some light over this?

Any help, input or thought is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue. For anyone else having similar problems this was because the underlying contentView of the `UISrollView` wasn't big enough.

Even though the `UITableView`, and even the views under it was visible, touches could not reach it since these are somehow registered through the `UIScrollView` contentView (for me, this was an `UIView` I added in the Interface Builder on top of the `UIScrollView`).

Also, if you are working with autoLayout, you have to change the contentViews constraints in the Interface Builder since `UIScrollView.contentSize` won't bother to listen to your commands.